# php is not returning complete data back to python

Tags: php, python

I am sending data to my laravel application in following format using requests

`r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/python-data', data = data)`
where data dict has data in following format

```
{'IN545ELFIBP3NAFAMZ': {'url': 'https://www.example.com/infinix-zero-4-x555-32gb-golden-4g-lte-6453687.html', 'color': 'Golden', 'image_url': 'https://example.com/p/infinix-7770-7863546-1-catalog_grid_3.jpg', 'brand': 'Infinix', 'title_alt': 'Zero 4 X555 - 32GB - Golden - 4G LTE', 'currency': 'Rs.', 'current_price': '22,999', 'old_price': 0, 'discount_percent': 0, 'rating_percent': 'width: 82%', 'total_ratings': '20'}, 'LE650EL10B3WSNAFAMZ': {'url': 'https://www.example.com/lenovo-zuk-z1-64gb-grey-6448906.html', 'color': 'Grey', 'image_url': 'https://example.com/p/lenovo-9978-6098446-1-catalog_grid_3.jpg', 'brand': 'Lenovo', 'title_alt': 'ZUK Z1 - 64GB - Grey', 'currency': 'Rs.', 'current_price': '36,999', 'old_price': 0, 'discount_percent': 0, 'rating_percent': 'width: 85%', 'total_ratings': '5'}}
```

and I am returning the complete data back to python

```
public function save(Request $request){
        return $request->all();
    }
```

but when I print the returned data in python, this is what I get
`print(r.text)`
`{"IN545ELFIBP3NAFAMZ":"total_ratings","LE650EL10B3WSNAFAMZ":"total_ratings"}`

Comment: first check what you receive in PHP.

Comment: @furas php itself is not receiving correct data.

Comment: I think nowadays people on stackoverflow just come to downvote your question instead answering it. Come on buddy, if you dont know the answer then why the hell you are downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

After spending a number of hours, the only problem was that I had to send the data as json

`r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/python-data', json = data)`
and it worked fine.